# Redirect to new window when page ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I was wondering why this code isn't working. I am trying to make a new tab open with a new URL when the original page loads up.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     window.location.href = "/pageb";      
});
```

Comment: have you included .min file?

Comment: This code won't open a new tab which anyway isn't possible without any user interraction . Otherwise, you could open thousand boring new tab containing ads...

Comment: @DevLakshman what is a `.min` file?

Comment: @charlietfl..jquery.min file

Comment: try  window.open("pagename"); instead of  window.location.href = "/pageb";

Comment: @A.Wolff Would I be able to change it using the .hover() function, so when the mouse hovers over any part of the body of the page the new tab opens

Comment: @YourDaily Still you will get tab blocked by popup blocker if not explecitely allowed for this website regarding user browser preference. Instead, you can bind click event to document and use `window.open('url');` but still depending user preference, you cannot be sure that it will open a new tab compare to a new popup window

Comment: Yes this will open new window on mouseover event.

Comment: If you are just wanting to direct to a new URL when the page loads, you're best using a header from the server (in PHP `header('Location: pageurl');`). If you do want to do it on interaction with the user, no need to bind to a click event (or use JS at all). Just put an `a` tag in there. If you want it in a new tab, `<a target="_blank" ...>`. Yes it's deprecated in HTML5, but all browsers still support it.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your console? Put something like an `alert('Im here);` in the callback to make sure it's actually firing.

Comment: @A.Wolff How would i go about changing the code so that it creates a pop up window instead. What i'm after is when someone is reading an article on my website there a new window or tab will automatically open with the latest articles from my website and a few links to our social media sites

Comment: @NileshMistry How would i modify the code to change it to work using .mousemove()

Comment: @KevinNagurski I am testing it in J Fiddle but nothing seems to be responding

Comment: What is your jFiddle url?

Comment: @KevinNagurski https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=h6CVs1JydU

Comment: @YourDaily You can use mouseover event of jquery. code should like  $("#yourid" ).mouseover(function() {
    window.open("yourpage");
  });

Comment: @NileshMistry hi would you be able to look at the code: $("body" ).mouseover(function() { window.open("google.com"); }); is it correct, I'm trying to make it so that if you mouse over the body of the page the window will open, thanks

Comment: @YourDaily Yes it will work.

Comment: @YourDaily Please check this URL https://jsfiddle.net/x002vebf/ only you need to give proper URL.

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
```

if this didnt work redirect after windows on load